# Linux (Ubuntu) Alert on desktop on full local disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, notification, hard-disk

I am looking for a desktop program that will monitor my local filesystems and pop up an alert once the usage reaches a certain threshold. I know lots of solutions for the server environment, but that would be overkill as I just want to monitor my desktop, which runs Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu already includes a disk space warning alert as part of [dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf).

You can configure the settings by installing the [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Start the dconf Editor:

```
dconf-editor
```

Press `CRTL + F` to show the find option.

Enter "disk space" and click on "Next"

[image: dconf editor]

You can set the free percent warning to whatever you like.

This example is from Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS but the instructions likely apply to other versions.